# What is the future of StackOverflow outside of the IT world?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Obviously StackOverflow (and the rest of paltry gang of 4) is very successful in IT.  I wonder if their concept can be taken to a non-technical communities, and perhaps replace [Yahoo! Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/) or at least compete with them?

What do you guys think about it?

Comment: There's probably about 10 questions that already ask this exact question, or have it answered somewhere inside them. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=yahoo+answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this very reason Fog Creek have developed the [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com) Framework to allow for you and others to create their own StackOverflow-style website.

Comment: true, but what about competing on the web instead of a product you have to pay for?

Comment: @Sasha: Where exactly do you suppose the StackExchange websites will exist?

Comment: It will NOT be free, at least not after 45 days :(

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at. Yahoo! Answers hosting surely isn't free either. Yahoo! pays for the servers, the service is still free to *end users*.